# IPhone App Build Successful But nothing shows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Very new to Iphone development here, I have a project which is successfully building (which is a first for me :) It loads the simulator but it just closes as soon as it loads, how can I debug this? It appears the Interface Builder xib files are not loading, I've added a xib thats from a hello world project, (they have different project names) Is this an issue?

Any advice would help,
Thanks!

Comment: Is anything being logged to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an error in the Debugger Console.  If it has to do with the XIB, it could be that you simply got the name wrong.

Another simple mistake is trying to use Outlets before viewDidLoad is called (for instance, in init).

In either case -- the message in the console will help.

Comment: Thank you shows how much I know about it, I didn't even realize the console was there :) I got "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'" I think I can continue my bumblings from here thank you again